# Holding legend between a number of plots

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I plot with different data sets and all plots are on the same axes. The issue  I am facing here is adding the legend and when i plot the next plot the legend of the first gets overwritten our overlapped. How can I have the legends of consecutive plots below the other and not over

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The thing with `legends` is that it creates a whole new legend whenever you call the command. You should therefore only draw legends once.

Here's an ***INCORRECT*** way to do it:

```
% THIS IS NOT CORRECT
plot(x1, y1, 'r.');   legend('first plot')
plot(x2, y2, 'g.');   legend('second plot')
plot(x3, y3, 'b.');   legend('third plot')
plot(x4, y4, 'k.');   legend('fourth plot')
```

which will create four overlapping legends. The ***RIGHT*** way to do it would be

```
plot(x1, y1, 'r.');   
plot(x2, y2, 'g.');   
plot(x3, y3, 'b.');   
plot(x4, y4, 'k.'); 

% only 1 call to legend
legend('first plot', 'second plot', 'third plot', 'fourth plot')
```

or, alternatively, to keep plot and legend entry together,

```
plot(x1, y1, 'r.');   L{1} = 'first plot';
plot(x2, y2, 'g.');   L{2} = 'second plot';   
plot(x3, y3, 'b.');   L{3} = 'third plot';   
plot(x4, y4, 'k.');   L{4} = 'fourth plot'; 

legend(L{:});
```